# jspdf, add new page, coordinates

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2pdf

I am using jspdf for html to pdf conversion.

First page is rendering the content perfectly. But when it comes to second page,  when I use `doc.cell(10, 10, cellWidth, 10, txt, j);` it is displaying in the middle of the page instead to appear at the start.

If I use `doc.text(10.10,"value")` its appearing at the right coordinates.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the contents to another page simply do

```
doc.addPage()
```

Example suppose you have two pages

```
 doc.text(10.10,"value")  //this will bne in the first page

 docaddPage() //this adds another page

 doc.text(10.10,"value") // this will be in page2
```

Comment: How do we auto detect if the page is full, and add the data to next page ?